# Does TextWrangler 4 break BBAutoComplete 1.5.3?

Tags: bbedit

I just installed TextWrangler 4, and now when I try to use BBAutoComplete version 1.5.3, I get the error message seen below.

[image]

Is there a workaround to make BBAutoComplete work with TextWrangler 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it breaks version 1.5.3, and yes, there's a workaround. But now it's unnecessary, because version 1.5.4 has been released and it solves the problem.

If for some reason you want to still use 1.5.3, you can do the following:

In the script `~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Scripts/BBAutoComplete`, there is a function `canCompleteInWindow(w)`. This function needs to be modified to work with TextWrangler 4.

Open the script in AppleScript Editor.

As it ships, there is a function in the script that reads

```
on canCompleteInWindow(w)
    tell application "TextWrangler"
        return class of w is in {text window, disk browser window}
    end tell
end canCompleteInWindow
```

Change it so it reads

```
on canCompleteInWindow(w)
    tell application "TextWrangler"
        return class of w is in {text window, disk browser window, project window}
    end tell
end canCompleteInWindow
```

Save the script. BBAutoComplete should now work with TextWrangler 4.

Comment: This is addressed in BBAutoComplete 1.5.4, which also includes other improvements to the script. http://c-command.com/blog/2012/04/25/bbautocomplete-1-5-4/

Comment: @MichaelTsai Thanks. Question and answer modified to reflect the update.